# Javascript plugins not working properly with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, plugins, turbolinks

I'm using share buttons (javascript plugins). When I open a page it shows that buttons, but when I open other page it disappear. It appear again when i refresh website. It working properly with jquery.turbolinks and without turbolinks gem, but without it website is very slow. How to make website faster?
My [website](http://www.philsart23.uk/), now plugins is working, because I removed turbolinks.

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require lightbox
//= require_tree .
//= require turbolinks
```

**application.html.erb** javascript plugins

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-588e44a9401a6d9f"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="st_insights_js" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js?publisher=630cdfb3-b6c5-4da7-a389-1c7d5340827d"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "630cdfb3-b6c5-4da7-a389-1c7d5340827d", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.1'
```

I tried to add one plugin in javascript file, but result same

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  stLight.options({publisher: "630cdfb3-b6c5-4da7-a389-1c7d5340827d",      doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-initialize the buttons, since the buttons.js script is not re-inserted through turbolinks... I'd try something like this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    stLight.readyRun = false;
    stLight.onReady(); // re-initialization
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add something like that?

```
// turbolinks addthis
var initAdthis;

initAdthis = function(){
    // Remove all global properties set by addthis, otherwise it won't reinitialize
    for (var i in window) {
        if (/^addthis/.test(i) || /^_at/.test(i)) {
            delete window[i];
        }
    }
    window.addthis_share = null;

    // Finally, load addthis
    $.getScript("http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=YOUR-PUBLISHER-ID");
}

// Trigger the function on both jquery's ready event and turbolinks page:change event
$(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
    initAdthis();
});
```